I ran into a problem that FastAPI returns the date and time with a difference of 3 hours from the one stored in the database
I use the Tortoise-orm model:
from tortoise import fields
from tortoise.models import Model
import uuid

class News(Model):
    news_id: str = fields.TextField(pk=True)
    title: str = fields.TextField()
    link: str = fields.TextField()
    img: str = fields.TextField()
    pub_date = fields.DatetimeField()
    description: str = fields.TextField()
    category: str = fields.TextField()
    text: str = fields.TextField()
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pub_date']

Here is my endpoint and method for getting data from the database:
@router.get('/news')
async def get_offset_news(start: int, end: int):
    try:
        print(await newsServices.get_offset_news(start=start, end=end))
        return await newsServices.get_offset_news(start=start, end=end)
    except Exception as error:
        handle_error(error=error)

async def get_offset_news(self, start: int, end: int):
    return await News.filter().offset(start).limit(end - start).values()

This is the format in which the date is stored in the database:
2024-05-10 18:58:35+03
Here's what print returns in the endpoint /news:
'pub_date': datetime.datetime(2024, 5, 10, 15, 58, 35, tzinfo=)
And finally, in what form the date comes in the response from the API:
"pub_date": "2024-05-10T15:58:35+00:00"
I can't figure out why +03 is changing to +00:00. I think it should be clarified that the database and API are on my home computer.
I have already tried to create a separate model for the response:
class NewsModel(BaseModel):
    news_id: str
    title: str
    link: str
    img: str
    pub_date: datetime
    description: str
    category: str
    text: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
        json_encoders = {
            datetime: lambda dt: dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
        }

But as a result, I got this answer: "pub_date": "2024-05-10 15:29:08+0000"
